# Japanese word for window sill

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for Japanese word for window sill, specifically the ***interior*** one.

[image: Window sill]

There is a specific word for a wide interior window sill in Russian *(подоконник)*. Is there an equivalent in Japanese? I googled a little and found:

> 窓{まど}の下{した}
>
> 嵌{は}め込{こ}み窓{まど}の棚{たな}

I also found:

> 窓{まど}の桟{さん}

but it appears to refer the ***outer*** window sill, the one facing the street.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

窓台 seems to be the specific word. 膳板 and 天板 are used to refer to the board used to form this 台.

- [窓の手前にある棚のような部分は何と呼ばれるのでしょうか？](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1190852871)
- [窓台 - Design Note](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/haws+kitchen/touch/20170724/1500874960)

  > 窓台って、言われても一般的には？？？だと思います。窓枠ならわかりやすいでしょうか？
  >   その４辺ある窓枠の、下の水平な面を。「窓台」と呼びます。
- [無垢板の窓台 - 新井建設公式ブログ](http://www.athome-arai.jp/blog/e650.html)
- [リフォームでオシャレな出窓に！特徴やメリット、注意点を知っておこう - LIMIA](https://limia.jp/idea/24328/)

  > 出窓を室内から見た時の、下部にある棚のような部分を「窓台」と呼びます。
- [膳板 - 住宅建築専門用語辞典](http://www.what-myhome.net/14se/zenita.htm)
- [膳板 - 木質建材・建具用語集](https://www.nasluck.co.jp/useful/dictionary/word.php?wid=04472&wdid=01&pg=1&jid=00061&row=03&ini=04)

But these words are fairly rare. To laypeople, you probably have to say something like 出窓のカウンター部分, 窓の下の平らなスペース, 窓枠の下の棚状の部分, etc.